# Using generating functions to solve a recurrence

Tags: number-theory, summation, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am trying to learn generating functions so I am trying this recurrence:

$$F(n) = 1 + \frac{n-1}{n}F(n-1)$$

But I am struggling with it. Luckily the base case can be anything since $F(1)$ will multiply it by $0$ anyway, so let's say $F(0) = 0$. Then I tried this:

$$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F(n)x^n$$

Remove base case $n=0$, split $F(n)$ into its parts:

$$G(x) = 0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{n} F(n-1) x^{n}$$

Simplify the first sum (accounting for $n=0$), pull $x$ out of the right sum and shift index:

$$G(x) = -1 + \frac{1}{1-x} + x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n+1} F(n) x^{n}$$

At this point I don't know how to simplify the right sum any further because I cannot simply pull out $\frac{n}{n+1}$ and replace the sum with $G(x)$ like I normally can with constant coefficients.

Just looking for hints because I want to solve this myself (as much as I can, anyway), please. What are the typical methods people use at this point?

Comment: Hint: find $G'(x)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Trying it and I think I see what you're implying but I don't know what I'm doing. If I take the derivative of $G(x)$ then doesn't that make the problem harder? $x^n$ would go to $nx^{n-1}$ and add another factor of $n$, and nothing cancels out. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dx} F(n) x^n = n F(n) x^{n-1} = \ldots $.

Comment: Does this imply that $x\dfrac{d}{dx} F(n) x^n = n F(n) x^{n} = \ldots$ so I replace the sum with $x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\dfrac{d}{dx} F(n) x^n$?

Comment: (Sigh)  $$\eqalign{ G'(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n F(n) x^{n-1} \cr &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n + (n-1) F(n-1)) x^{n-1} \cr&= x G'(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1} \cr}$$

Comment: Is the sigh really necessary? Not all of us are naturally gifted at this

Comment: Check the first link of [this](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=recurrence+generating+function) ;)

Comment: @Masacroso, while I understand the intention of "LMGTFY", keep in mind that Google gives different results for different people based on their search histories. Therefore, what appears as the first link for you, will not necessarily be the first link for someone else. It would be more constructive to provide the desired link at the outset.

Comment: I understand @Joel but I doubt seriously that this search go for different results. Anyway [this is the link](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Generating-Functions.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Life will be more pleasant if we let $kF(k)=W(k)$. Then we are looking at  $W(n)=n+W(n-1)$. The generating function is straightforward, and then we can obtain the generating function of $F$.

Comment: Ah then it's just the sum of integers $W(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, so $F(n) = \frac{n+1}{2}$. Is it always valid to make substitutions like this? For example what if I made substitution $2^kF(k) = W(k)$ (for some other problem), or $\binom{n}{k}F(k) = W(k)$ or $\frac{k}{k+3}F(k) = W(k)$, etc.

Comment: @user51819: Yes, we can make substitutions of the first and third type. There is a potential problem with the second, since for fixed $n$ we have after a while $\binom{n}{k}=0$. Note that if you wish you can use the generating function approach for $W(n)$ in our case, and then manipulate suitably to get the generating function for $F(n)$

Comment: Is it normally the case that substitutions exist? If not, what about the derivation technique Robert Israel was hinting at above?

Comment: Often there is no useful substitution. The one I suggested comes naturally from looking at the structure of the recurrence. So does the differentiation technique suggested by Robert Israel.

Answer (score 4):

The usual GF-approach may go through the following lines. We have $F(0)=0$ and $n F(n) = n + (n-1) F(n-1)$. Assuming that
$$ G(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}F(n) x^n = \sum_{n\geq 1}F(n) x^n,\tag{1} $$
we have:
$$ x\cdot G'(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} n F(n)\,x^{n}=\sum_{n\geq 0} n F(n)\,x^{n}, \tag{2}$$
$$ x^2\cdot G'(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} (n-1) F(n-1)\, x^n,\tag{3} $$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}n\,x^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\tag{4}$$
hence the recurence relation turns into the pseudo-DE
$$ x G'(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+x^2 G'(x)\tag{5} $$
leading to $G'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$ and $G(x)=K+\frac{1}{2(1-x)^2}$. Since $G(0)=0$ we have $K=-\frac{1}{2}$, hence:

$$ G(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\binom{n+1}{1}x^n \tag{6} $$
by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), and $F(n)=\frac{n+1}{2}$ for any $n\geq 1$ readily follows.

Comment: I was with you up until the combinatoric stars and bars stuff, how does that factor into this exactly?

Comment: (I also didn't quite catch the rationale behind the jump from $xG'(x)$ to $x^2G'(x)$, what was done here and why

Comment: First fact (stars and bars): $$\frac{1}{(1-z)^{m+1}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+m}{n}x^n$$

Comment: @user51819: Second fact (index shift): $$ x\cdot \sum a_n x^n = \sum a_{n} x^{n+1} = \sum a_{n-1} x^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in an easier proof:

Observe:

$F(1)=1$, $F(2)=\frac{3}{2}$, $F(3)=2$, $F(4)=\frac{5}{2}$ $\dots$

Now it is easy to get the pattern $F(n)=\frac{n+1}{2}$ and prove it by induction.

First you can check that the induction base $F(1)=1$ holds.

In the induction step,
assume $F(n)=\frac{n+1}{2}$. 
Then $$F(n+1)= 1 + \frac{n+1-1}{n+1}F(n)=1+\frac{n}{n+1}\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac{n+2}{2},$$ where we used the induction assumption.